# Why is the logit of estimated value of a dependent variable equated to a linear combination of the independent variables?

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

I am reading this book which derives the formula for logistic regression and it states that if Y_i is an estimated probability than ln(Y_i/(1-Y_i)) = a+bX1 +cX2... but I don't understand why these expressions can be equated?

Comment: This is a way to define the logistic model. If you are meant to show that this equation follows from a different formulation of the logistic model, you should share us that context.

Comment: I'm wondering why the two concepts can be equated. One being the logit odds ratio of an estimated dependent variable and the other being the linear combination of independent variables

Comment: The right hand side suggests linear regression.  But presumably $Y$ only ever makes sense with values between $0$ and $1$ (e.g. a probability or proportion), and extrapolating the line would give values above and below this.  So you need another approach, and using $\log(Y/(1-Y))$ is a possibility which can make sense in some cases